# Why do I have to call my protocol functions two times to make it work?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm currently building a simple app to learn the protocol - delegate functionality. However my code doesn't work, even after I edited the way I did in my first practice app where it worked. In the `FirstViewController` there is a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. When the user taps on the `UIButton`, a segue brings them to the `SecondViewController` where they should enter their name into a `UITextField`. After that, they can press the `UIButton` in the `SecondViewController` and the entered Name should be displayed in the `UILabel` in the `FirstViewController`.

I can't figure out why I have to call the protocol function two times in the `@IBAction backButtonPresses()`. Also, I can't figure out how to handle the same protocol function in the `FirstViewController`.

Here's the code for the `FirstViewController.swift` file:

```swift
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    var labelText = ""
    let secondVC = SecondViewController()
    
    
    func changeLabelText(name: String) {
        labelText = secondVC.enteredName
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondVC", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        destinationVC?.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nameLabel.text = secondVC.enteredName
    }
    
}
```

And here's the code of the `secondViewController`:

```swift
import UIKit

protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func changeLabelText(name: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    
    
    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    
    var enteredName: String = ""
    
    func changeLabelText(name: String) {
        enteredName = name
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        changeLabelText(name: nameTextField.text ?? "")
        delegate?.changeLabelText(name: nameTextField.text ?? "")
        print("das ist der name \(enteredName)")
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call any delegate method twice in `backButtonPressed`. You are calling two completely different `changeLabelText` methods. One is in `SecondViewController`, the other is on the delegate.

The call to `changeLabelText` in the `SecondViewController` is quite unnecessary. In fact, the `enteredName` property in `SecondViewController` is unnecessary. Also, `SecondViewController` should not be implementing its own delegate.

The call to `changeLabelText` on `delegate` is all you need. You just need to update the implementation of `changeLabelText` in `FirstViewController` to update the label's text with the new value.

```
func changeLabelText(name: String) {
    nameLabel.text = name
}
```

Do not reference the `secondVC` property in `FirstViewController`. In fact, remove that property completely. It's not needed and it's referencing a completely different instance of `SecondViewController` than the one you actually present via segue.

I also suggest renaming the delegate method from `changeLabelText` to something more general such as `enteredText`. `SecondViewController` can be used by any other view controller to obtain some text. It's not specific to changing a label.

Here's your two view controllers with suggested changes:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    func enteredText(name: String) {
        nameLabel.text = name
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondVC", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        destinationVC?.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func enteredText(name: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        delegate?.changeLabelText(name: name)
        print("das ist der name \(name)")
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i jus edited the code and it worked! Thank you so much! I realized how confusing my code was and now i kind of understand how the code is executed! Thanks Man